# performance searching using a map or a slice

Tags: arrays, go, struct, maps, slice

I have a struct called Users

```
type Users struct {
    name string
    job  string
}
```

Search function

```
func search() (users []Users, err error) {

    users = make([]Users, 0)
    rows, _ := mysql.Query("select name,job from users")

    for rows.Next() {
        var user Users
        rows.Scan(&user.Name, &user.Job)
        users = append(users, user)
    }
    return
}
```

As you may notice I am working with slice  but due to the huge number of result that I have to handle I must work on performance, I have heard that the map are more faster in term of performance but I don't know if my example is included?
If it's the case could you please suggest me via my code who to write a map array and try to append for each line of the query result.

Comment: 1/ faster for what? maps and arrays have different goals. 2/ maybe it's faster to do any processing you might want BEFORE fetching results, AKA in the db query, databases are built to be fast 3/ Benchmark benchmark benchmark, until you identified the bottleneck optimization is useless. Your db query could take 5 seconds to respond and using a different data structure might get you a 15 ms gain, is this reasonable to spend time on the later rather than the former?

Comment: thanks @mpm for response actually faster in term of getting result from multiple query of the same format and a thousands of result  , for that purpose i 'd to think which will be ideal i did some searches before , for example :https://www.darkcoding.net/software/go-slice-search-vs-map-lookup/ but i didn't understand

Comment: There is no X is better than Y answer here. If there would be we wouldn't have slices *and* maps. Nothing in your code does any kind of lookup, so I'm not quite sure what the relevance of the linked article is. If you want to speed up the append operations, [give your slice an appropriate capacity](https://blog.golang.org/slices)

Comment: Take a look at [this lookup](https://www.darkcoding.net/software/go-slice-search-vs-map-lookup/)

Answer (score 1):

A slice/array is an (ordered) list of items. You could easily access item #42 but getting *the item called "foo"* is expensive (you need to walk through the list until you find it).

A map is a key/value store: Accessing one item via it's key is fast, but walking through all items costs more than through a slice/array.

The question is: What do you want to do with the data?
Do you want to grab individual items -> Use a map
Do you want to use the whole list -> Use a slice/array

Here's an (untested) sample using your code to fill a map, but that might be a very bad solution depending on your usage case.

In case you're writing a generic search function, consider adding some server-side filter logic. Nothing is worse than fetching the whole database table and then filtering it in memory!

```
func search() (users map[string]Users, err error) {

    users = make(map[string]Users)
    rows, _ := mysql.Query("select name,job from users")

    for rows.Next() {
        var user Users
        rows.Scan(&user.Name, &user.Job)
        users[user.Name] = user
    }
    return
}
```

See also https://blog.golang.org/go-maps-in-action